# Is there any code that can use to find complete cases in JSON?

Tags: python, json, missing-data

I'm new to the JSON thing. But I need to know which of the responses contains NA or missing values. Do anyone knows any code can be used in Python to print out the responses that are not completed.

This type of response that I have. The example below shows that ID 134-bc has no age, gender and job information.

```
[{"user_id":"123-ab",
"language":"English",
"demographic_data":{"age":22,"gender":"F","job":4}
"responses":{"Question 1":3,"Question 2":2,"Question 4":1}},
{"user_id":"134-bc",
"language":"Chinese",
"demographic_data":{"age":"","gender":"","job":""}
"responses":{"Question 1":3,"Question 2":2,"Question 4":1}},
{"user_id":"123-bc",
"language":"Chinese",
"demographic_data":{"age":"21","gender":"M","job":2}
"responses":{"Question 1":3,"Question 2":2,"Question 4":1}}
]
```

Output 
I want it in two separate files.

The complete cases in one file.

```
[{"user_id":"123-ab",
"language":"English",
"demographic_data":{"age":22,"gender":"F","job":4}
"responses":{"Question 1":3,"Question 2":2,"Question 4":1}},
{"user_id":"123-bc",
"language":"Chinese",
"demographic_data":{"age":"21","gender":"M","job":2}
"responses":{"Question 1":3,"Question 2":2,"Question 4":1}}
]
```

The uncomplete cases in another file that will have probably more than this example.

```
[{"user_id":"134-bc",
"language":"Chinese",
"demographic_data":{"age":"","gender":"","job":""}
"responses":{"Question 1":3,"Question 2":2,"Question 4":1}}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Python dict, you can test whether attributes are totally missing with `in` or `not in`.  If you consider a blank field as "missing", then you can use `dict.get()`, which returns None for missing data.

```
DEFAULT_FIELDS = ["age", "gender", "job"]

def is_missing_data(record, field_names=None):
    field_names = DEFAULT_FIELD_NAMES if field_names is None else field_names
    demographic_data = record["demographic_data"]

    # If "not all" fields are present/truthy, then some data is missing.
    return not all(demographic_data.get(name) for name in field_names)
```

Then, you can split data as follows:

```
incomplete_records = [rec for rec in records if is_missing_data(rec)]
complete_records = [rec for rec in records if not is_missing_data(rec)]

with open('incomplete.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(incomplete_records, f)

with open('complete.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(complete_records, f)
```

Comment: You could potentially even abstract this a layer out, and have a dictionary for the outer fields: demographic_data itself, language, etc.

Comment: @MadaManu, that's a good point... with a schema this could be done in a more generic fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code to output the txt files:

```
with open('complete cases.txt', 'w') as f, open('incomplete cases.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f.write(str([i for i in list_of_json if i['demographic_data']['age']]))
    f2.write(str([i for i in list_of_json if not i['demographic_data']['age']]))
```

Comment: Hi, I already try the code, How to declare the file. Since I get this error. 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'complete cases.txt'

Comment: @farahamiramh Edited try again

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple things:
Check for the existence of the key:

```
'key' in [userid] #return true or false
```

Likewise if it is not present:

```
if 'key' not in [userid]:
    return something
```

Check if the key has a value, else return default value:

```
userId.get('key', 'null')
```

```
def get_attribute(data, attribute, default_string):
    return data.get(attribute) or 'default_string'
```